# How to refactore without breaking the code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am trying to refactor this code but I keep on breaking it.

```js
let shoppingList1 = [
  { itemName: 'Bread', price: 11.0 },
  { itemName: 'Milk', price: 7.0 },
  { itemName: 'Cheese', price: 19.5 },
];

function shoppingList(shoppingList1) {
  return (
    shoppingList1[0].price + shoppingList1[1].price + shoppingList1[2].price
  );
}

console.log(shoppingList(shoppingList1));
```

Comment: How were you trying to refactor it? What's the goal of the refactoring? How is it broken?

Comment: I guess you want to add up all prices? Map the array: `list.map(item => item.price)` to get an array of prices only, then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reduce function to make that sum.

It works that way:
The reduce has a loop inside it, and it iterates trough all items from your array.

The function receives another function as parameter, it will execute that function in every iteration.
It also has an accumulator, that stores the value you returned every iteration.
In the example I'm setting the initial value of the accumulator as zero.

Since I have passed an arrow function that sums the accumulator with the price of the item object, it will achieve the result you are looking for

```
result = shoppingList1.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return acc + item.price
}, 0)
```

Here is one example with the sum function being created before the execution of the reduce.

```
const sumPrices = (acc, item) => {
    return acc + item.price
}

result = shoppingList1.reduce(sumPrices, 0)
```

Here is the link to the documentation of reduce. It's a little complex in the beggining, but help's a lot to write your code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thanks for your edit on the question. Please clarify by commenting, don't add intent yourself. This could be a guess and might not what the author wanted. So, let the original poster edit and improve their question. BTW: Your answer explains _functional concepts_ (i.e. `reduce`) very well. A 2 step refactoring-recipe for advanced JavaScript developers. Assuming they want "Summing-up the total of a shopping-cart" using "functional concepts of JS"